# Converting cluster of Points to Polygons using QGIS

Tags: qgis, polygon, qgis-plugins, clustering, point-in-polygon

I have an input point layer that is grouped into clusters, so I want to have each cluster of points converted into polygon.

This question [How to convert a set of points to a polygon based on a specific field in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/68149/how-to-convert-a-set-of-points-to-a-polygon-based-on-a-specific-field-in-qgis) (*this question was removed*) seems to come close to what I wanted by it hasn't been answered.

So basically, I need an algorithm in QGIS that will convert each cluster of points (based on attribute field) as seen below into a polygons?

[image]

I have tried ["Point2One"](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/points2one/) plugin and it gave me wrong result seen below...

[image]

A copy of my data is found [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/agbkdeerzcsrnip/Points_to_Polygons.zip?dl=0).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Convex hull - as mentioned by Kazuhito - is one option, but - depending on the cluster shape - you will get more appropriate polygons using **concave hulls**, for example implemented in [ConcaveHull plugin](http://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/concavehull/).

[image]

Answer (score 10):

You may be interested in *Convex Hull* which is in `Processing | QGIS geoalgorithms | Vector geometry tools`. There is *Field* option which can be used with *Method* `Create convex hulls based on field`.

[image]

Or from the menu `Vector | Geoprocessing Tools | Convex Hull(s)`.

[image]

Many Thanks, Techie_Gus and underdark for information.

Comment: Note that in the latest QGIS release, i.e. 2.18, the Geoprocessing Tools menu is no longer under the Vector menu. It is now only accessible through the processing toolbox.

Comment: @Techie_Gus If you don't see a Geoprocessing Tools menu, that's a sign that you have an old Processing version in your plugin folder that should be deleted

Comment: Thanks @underdark. I will add drop-down list of 2.14/2.18 cases for clarity.

Comment: @underdark I can see the processing tools menu as a separate menu but not under the vectors menu anymore. And by the way, I use the OSGEO4W installer.

Comment: What to do with polygons that overlap each other?

Comment: @nagib Could you expound your comment?

Comment: Thanks to @underdark my Processing is now working as it is supposed to be, and the different geoprocessing tools are now under the Vector menu! Indeed there was a processing folder in the plugins folder under c:\users and another entry under C:\OSGeo4W64. This essentially invalidates my first comment and consequently, an OSGeo4W installation should be no different than a standalone installation (at least in this context).

Comment: @Techie_Gus Thanks for your follow-up and feed back information. Edited the answer accordingly. (and Glad to know your Vector menu is good now, too.)

Comment: @Kazuhito The picture in the response shows the polygons that overlap. Is this a problem for you?

Comment: Thanks @nagib. To me it indicates interspersed distribution of this attribute. Overlaps occur in both convex and concave hulls (as OP needs control by attribute field). But it can be problematic for OP.