# Creating convex hull of set of points using QGIS

Tags: qgis, point, polygon-creation, convex-hull

I have a shapefile layer with a set of points.

[image]

I would like to enclose them (or turn them) into the polygon (with the line in the middle).

I tried this:

- [Converting cluster of Points to Polygons using QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/229955/converting-cluster-of-points-to-polygons-using-qgis)
- [Creating Minimum Convex Polygon - Home Range from Points in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/283111/creating-minimum-convex-polygon-home-range-from-points-in-qgis)

which led me to the `Convex Hull` tool.

Unfortunately, it looks like, that this operation can be applied to the cluster of points instead of single located points.

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Instead of using the ["Convex hull"](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#convex-hull) tool, use the ["Minimum bounding geometry"](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#minimum-bounding-geometry) tool by specifying the desired type of geometry output as shown in the image below.

[image]

Comment: It appears to be valid, however once I set the minimum bounding geometry and selecting Node (one of the column apart from Lot & Lan) I am getting an empty layer.
I found the similar issue here:
https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/283111/creating-minimum-convex-polygon-home-range-from-points-in-qgis
which hasn't been resolved really.
Any ideas about how to make the layer visible?

Comment: If I choose Convex hull, then I am getting:
Feature could not be written to Bounding_geometry_40560c1f_a69b_4202_905d_4edcec325f04

Comment: If the layer is not visible, there was an error during processing. Can you try with another layer of points ?

Comment: I have this one only populated so far. I can add it again.

Comment: Not needed mate. I found the mistake. I should have left the field point empty! Thank you for your help!