# Create contours based on text attribute of point data (isogloss map)

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, contour

I am trying to make an isogloss map in QGIS to map dialect differences.
I have made a point shapefile in which each point represents a place, and the different pronunciations are put in the attribute table. Obviously I have a massive amount of attributes.

As it is not convenient to just constantly change the attribute for the symbology, I wanted to create contours that separate the areas with different pronunciation.

I tried using contour, but it doesn't accept string data.

Imagine the points are plotted as follows, with the colours relating to a specific attribute
[image: Picture without isogloss]

The countours I would like to have are something like this (for the same attribute)
[image: Picture with isoglosses]

I wonder if there is some way to do this easily, so far the only option I found was using voronoi polygons which I then merge based on the characteristics, which is quite a lengthy process, considering I have quite a few attributes to repeat this for. (The other way is changing the symbology and drawing manually)

Comment: may be this is what you are looking for: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/229955/converting-cluster-of-points-to-polygons-using-qgis or try to use the processing tool: Minimum bounding geometry

Comment: Maybe this thread can be relevant, please check [Displaying multipoint features as polygon using QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/322739/displaying-multipoint-features-as-polygon-using-qgis)

Answer (score 5):

I think the contour idea won't work, your text data is not a continuous phenomena as the elevation.

I suppose you had better to create Voronoi polygons on your point data using Processing toolbox.

[image: The sample point data]

I added 10% to the extent of the layer to get polygons outside the extent of the points. You can set another value for you.

[image: Create Voronoi cells]

This way you get areas around your points (without gaps and overlaps). The Voronoi cells inherit the attributes of the points.

[image: Voronoi cells and points]

Using dissolve from processing toolbox you can merge polygons with the same string attribute:

[image: Dissolve Voronoi polygons]

Now you can create a thematic map on your text column:

[image]

Comment: I think there are two more steps can be applied. (3) Apply a Convex hull for all points (4) Make a difference between the result of Dissolving and the result of Step 3. But indeed your answer looks exactly what I wanted to propose, +1

Answer (score 1):

It may also be worthwhile considering having additional data that can be used to 'bound' your polygons. That is - perhaps topographic features which would 'bound' a certain language or dialect.

eg: A river - people on west of river vs people on east of river. Or perhaps a country/state boundary, road/hwy etc.
This additional data may help 'cut' your interpolated polygons to be more fitting to the topographic features which bound the languages.